# How to change values from file using a dictionary on Python

Tags: python

I'm doing a biology degree and feel like I've been thrown in at the deep end with python, as I've never coded before, and the 'teaching' was pretty much non-existent. Anyway, they've given this file of gene sequences, which pretty much looks like :

```
En123, ATGCCGAATA

En124, ATGCCAGTAT
```

but much longer with way more genes. They want it converted into a protein sequence. 
So far, I've got...

```
with open('DNA_sequences.csv', 'r') as f:

for line in f:
    columns = line.rstrip("\n").split(",") #remove end of line charcters and split at commas to produce a list
    ensemblID = columns[0] #ensemblID is first element in our list
    gene_sequence = columns [1] #gene_name is second element in list
```

wasn't sure if I needed the columns or not.

I've also made a dictionary for the protein sequence, with the amino acid and the corresponding codon.

```
protein_sequence= {'TTT': 'F', 'CTT': 'L', 'GAT':'D'} etc.
```

So I'm wondering how to I split the gene sequence in my file into codons, then pass it through the dictionary so I get the sequence of amino acid names.

```
i.e. gene_sequence= TTTCTTTGAT to protein_sequence= FLD
```

(Sorry for being so incompetent!)

Comment: are the amino acids always 3 characters?

Comment: What Reading Frame will you use? Forward 1?

Comment: Don't you need the starting codon to be TAC, corresponding to methionine?

Comment: Use [biopython](https://github.com/biopython/biopython) !

Comment: About the start codon, I was only giving those as examples

Comment: I can't use biopython as the whole assignment is to assess how we use python- pointless I know, but that's the way it is

Comment: @RichSmith yeah, so any three of the A,T,C,G bases codes for one amino acid, then a specific sequence of amino acids codes for a protein.

Answer (score 0):

so to load the csv I'd use the csv module like so:

```
import csv

with open(filepath) as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    data = [row for row in reader]
```

then to convert the gene sequence:

```
geneSeq = "TTTCTTTGAT"

acids = [geneSeq[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(geneSeq), 3)]

proteinSequenceString = ""
for a in acids:
    proteinSequenceString += protein_sequence[a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `gene_sequence` in chunks of 3 and lookup codons in your dictionary:

```
>>> gene_sequence = 'TTTCTTGAT'
>>> protein_sequence = {'TTT': 'F', 'CTT': 'L', 'GAT': 'D'}
>>> ''.join(protein_sequence[gene_sequence[i:i+3]] for i in range(0, len(gene_sequence), 3))
'FLD'
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I should have mentioned above that the file with the gene names and sequences is a csv file (not sure if this makes a difference, or even what this means but just in case), so when even I run the program it comes back that '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len(). I think it means it can't read the gene_sequence length